# Can't make an MP4 movie height to change and fit in Material Box both landscape and portait

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, html5-video, mp4

I learn JavaScript React and now I have problem with positioning of an MP4 movie.
I have a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mp4-positioning-problem-sj6t9?file=/src/FileContentRenderer.jsx:256-278)

Check the file  FileContentRenderer.jsx where the html5-video is used with MP4.

I want it to fit the material `Box` in portrait with let's say `height: '20vw` and landscape but whatever I try I can't get it to change I must have missed some fundamental please advice

Like this, here the movie should be just a 4th of the height and not this mega high.
Whatever I try this height can't be reduced please advice?

I have this Material `withStyles` that is not working making the MP4 look good

```
const styles = theme => ({
    viewerWrapperMp4: {
        background: 'black',
        width: '100%',
        height: '20vw',
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    viewerMp4: {
        width: 'auto',
        height: '100%',
    },
    outer: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
});
```

It does not matter what movie I try the movie refuses to fit the Box

[image]

Comment: Do you need a fixed height for all videos with any kind of aspect ratio?

Comment: There's a large amount of code to wade through in your code sandbox. It would help if you could simplify the sandbox to the minimum amount of code necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Do you want to fit the video inside a fixed width and height width or do you just want to adjust the height of the video container? Your question isn't clear!

Comment: @SoroushBgm The video should adjust width height keeping aspect ratio but stay in the Material Box bounderism. Both in portrait or landscape Basically a normal video viewer. This is only for previewing the video before uploading it somewhere

Comment: Maybe I should use the [Material-ui video player](https://codesandbox.io/s/o9znq5ppj5?resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675). Now I use the htm5-video. I learn react it's hard especially GUI's

Answer (score 1):

I believe this piece of code is what you're looking for.
It keeps the height and aspect ratio. It makes a video centered. and the width of video is variable.

```css
.video-container {
background: black;
width: 100%;
height: 20vw;
text-align: center;
}

.video {
width: auto;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
 <video class="video" controls>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video> 
<div>
```

Obviously, you can't keep both width and height fixed while your videos has different aspect ratios. One of them must be variable.
This code keeps height fixed.

Comment: Thanks I think I tried similar but there's a [ghost in the machine](https://snipboard.io/wHhFb1.jpg) because the video cant be sized. Here I try your code. I look upward in the tree to see if there is other css sass but I dont think so still Video(small 2Mb ) is big

Comment: Here's  the small 2MB [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c9L6Q97dsUxCxUkRzNUUZTJeqF2nVzEt/view?usp=sharing) I use

Comment: Surely it’s not a ghost :)) height: 20vw uses the width of whole window. Try replacing that with another specific amount in pixels. Like 200px.

Comment: Not working in the [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-new-content-mp4-positioning-problem-w2if4?file=/src/styles/item-renderer.scss) There got to be something I missed because what you suggest should work I know

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your code to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/mp4-positioning-problem-forked-nfdcy) and in the final result, you should change video element CSS to this:

```
  maxHeight: "20vw";
```

Comment: This seems to work but what is the 44 number doing  "MuiBox-root-44"

Comment: This feels like a hack, where can I read about this? Is this applied to all material `MuiBox`'  in the app or only the direct parent Component  `<CardContent`?

Comment: I was just now rewriting the code using material-ui `withStyles`

Comment: I don't know why exactly did they name it like this, but I find it by inspecting elements and find out they set `margin-top` to `16px` in this class. every UI library has its own weird className for every element. You couldn't remember them (they usually change in every version of the library) so the best way is to learn how to inspect and find out the className and rewrite their value.

Comment: I don't like this hack. I want to control the Components trough css or Material ´withStyles`

Comment: Thanks maybe you could make it work without using this "root" hack. I see the `video {
  max-height: 20vw;
}` is what makes it works and I do the same in my `withStyles` and css with no luck

Comment: I see what you mean, it is not a lovely way but it is common facing a situation to do this kind of hack while using UI libraries. 
And, Yeah exactly. The most important one is `video` tag style. two other classes rewriting is just for fitting as much as it could be. You could test it by commenting on `codeSandBox`. Hope you find the answer useful.

Comment: I made the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mp4-positioning-problem-sj6t9?file=/src/FileContentRenderer.jsx:256-278) smaller easier to work with and changed SCSS to Material `withStyles` If you know Material `withStyles` maybe you can have a look what I have done wrong

Comment: I've fixed your issue. please see [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/mp4-positioning-problem-forked-nfdcy) . I've added a class to the video element in `video-viewer.jsx` and set `maxHeight` of it to `20vw`.

Comment: Thanks you're  so good at this and I learn so much from you. If you want to [contribute to the app](https://github.com/erikswed/Greta-100-React-Web-App) I would love that. Change your answer to reflect your  `videoElement: {
    maxHeight: "20vw"`
  }` and I will accept applying bounty

Comment: You're so welcome. I'm happy to help. it would be great, also you could contact me whenever there was an issue. sure I'll change the answer to the ending result. Thanks for that.

Comment: My [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100016526263449) , please be my Friend

Comment: Thank you, I'm not in Facebook :) and even more social networks. just messangers.